# gzip compression not working with nginx and centos 7

Tags: nginx, gzip, plesk

I want to enable gzip compression on my virtual host with nginx. My control panel is Plesk17 but I have access to server root. I found the vhost nginx config file in this dir:

```
/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts
```

and add this codes in ***server*** block to enable gzip:

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable msie6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types    text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
gzip_vary on;
```

After all and restarting the nginx, when I check the gzip status, it looks disabled!

For your information, I also have this comments at the top of my config file:

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
```

What's wrong? how can I enable the gzip?

Comment: Check with your cloud provider. It seems they don't allowing customization of nginx files. You would need to change everything from plesk. So check with them what needs to be done. Because lot of such providers give limited access to things that can be done directly from instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable gzip compression for particular domain open **Domains > example.com > Apache & nginx Settings > Additional nginx directives** and add directives to this section.
If you want to enable it server-wide just create new file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf` add content there and restart nginx.